# adding column in CSV file using awk

Tags: command-line, text-processing, awk

I need to a add a column in CSV file from an array using awk.

For example,

`input.csv`

```
a,10
b,11
```

`array = (100 200)`

`output.csv` should look like

```
a,10,100
b,11,200
```

I tried this command but it does not work

```
awk -F"," 'BEGIN { OFS = "," } {for (x in array) $3=array[x]; print}' input.csv> output.csv
```

Comment: Just to point out that awk is not well suited for CSVs unless it’s a file with very simple data. Once you get into columns with commas in their values, and double quotes, this isn’t the right tool. Using a tool that is designed to parse CSV files is much better like xsv, csvtool, or python, or any other

Answer (score 7):

Do you have to use `awk` for this?  The `paste` utility was designed exactly for this sort of thing.  Assuming `array` is a shell array:

```
array=(100 200)
printf "%s\n" "${array[@]}" | paste -d, input.csv - > output.csv
```

The `printf` is simply to put each array member on a new line.  `paste` then pastes together input lines from input.csv and `-` (i.e. the piped output from `printf`), using a comma as a delimiter.

---

If your array happens to be a newline separated file, e.g. array.txt:

```
100
200
```

then it is even easier:

```
paste -d, input.csv array.txt > output.csv
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that shell variables (including arrays) are not available inside `awk`. You need to pass them explicitly via `-v` option. Moreover you cannot pass the whole array, but you can put array into single variable and split it inside `awk`:

```
awk -va="$(echo "${array[@]}")" 'BEGIN{OFS=FS=","; split(a,b," ")}{print $0,b[NR]}' input.csv
```

This will work as long as you don't have spaces inside array elements.

Comment: actually you can http://stackoverflow.com/a/15787182/2002471