# Append Value to end of the file based on match content

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

My Script Below

```
###BEGIN#
#!/bin/bash
### Daily Volume Growth
echo "Volume Name     Total Size   `date +%F`" >> volgrow

echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume1 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume2 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume3 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
###END#
```

**My OUTPUT is Below**

```
Volume Name     Total Size 2017-05-25
/vol/Volume1/ 5632GB
/vol/Volume2/ 2136GB
/vol/Volume3/ 5110GB
```

**My Requirement is Below**

```
Volume Name     Total Size 2017-05-25  2017-05-26 2017-05-27
/vol/Volume1/ 5632GB  5633GB 5630GB
/vol/Volume2/ 2136GB  2137GB 2138GB
/vol/Volume3/ 5110GB 5109GB 5111GB
```

Comment: can you post the raw output of `echo "ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume1"` ?

Comment: Filesystem               total       used      avail capacity  Mounted on

/vol/Volume1/          5632GB     5224GB      407GB      93%  /vol/Volume1/

/vol/Volume1/.snapshot        0GB      534GB        0GB     ---%  /vol/Volume1/.snapshot

Comment: @RaviAnkam, comments don't really work for that, the formatting options are rather limited, it's better to [edit] clarifications like that to the question. That parsing of the `df` could probably be streamlined a bit. Adding new data would also be easier on a separate line, and for long time intervals might be easier to read. (Not that any of this answers your question.)

Comment: Ah, this may be relevant: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/226000/adding-column-in-csv-file-using-awk

Answer (score 1):

```
###BEGIN#
#!/bin/bash
### Daily Volume Growth
#### Will execute once when file not exist and add first entry in the file
if [ ! -f volgrow ]; then
      echo "Volume Name     Total Size   `date +%F`" >> volgrow
    echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume1 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ 
print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
    echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume2 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ 
print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
    echo "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume3 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ 
print $1,$2 }'`" >> volgrow
fi

#### get all data in different variables 
line1 = echo "`date +%F`"
line2 = "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume1 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`   "
line3 = "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume2 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`   "
line4 = "`ssh 192.168.1.2 df -h Volume3 |head -2 | tail -1 | awk '{ print $1,$2 }'`   "

###########  append variable value in line 1, 2, 3, 4
sed -i -e "1s%$%\t$line1%" volgrow
sed -i -e "2s%$%$line2%" volgrow
sed -i -e "3s%$%$line3%" volgrow
sed -i -e "4s%$%$line4%" volgrow
###END#
```

Comment: [Brevity is acceptable, but fuller explanations are better](http://unix.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer).